# How to view files uploaded by user with php?

Tags: php, filesystems

I have a script for letting users uploading pictures and videos in my website. I need to view them, how do I set the proper permissions?

```
chmod("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"], 0755)
```

This doesn't work, I want the files to be available for me to use in windows, since I would need to work on that. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to set the chmod of a file uploaded by PHP, as the web server will already "own" the file.

**Handling The File**

In order to view it in your browser, you need to ensure you moved the file from the temp directory to your upload directory with something similar to the following:

```
// Define where the uploads directory is
$upload_dir = '/var/www/uploads/';
// Define the upload path from $upload_dir
$upload_file = $upload_dir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

// Move the tmp uploaded file to the uploads directory
if( !move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_file) ) {
    // Handle the failure to move the temp file
    echo "File did not upload";
};
```

You can check that the file is getting moved to the appropriate location by var dumping the path or checking the file exists.

```
// Is path correct?
var_dump($upload_file);
// Did the file get moved?
var_dump(file_exists($upload_file));
```

**Still Issues?**

If the file is not getting uploaded to the server there are several issues that could be the case. See this PHP Docs [page on uploads pitfalls](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php). In summary:

- You are trying to directly access the file and the uploads directory is above you webserver document root, therefore not servable by the daemon.
- *upload_max_filesize* defaults to 2Mb, which is usually too small for pictures/video. (php.ini)
- *max_execution_time* defaults to 60s which could be exceeded in the case of large pictures or video on slow connections. (php.ini)
- *memory_limit* can be exceeded when uploading larger files. (php.ini)

Check these in the [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) and increase their values to suit your needs if needed.

Another option to check is that the uploads directory is not blocked from serving images due to an *.htaccess* file mod rewrite.

Comment: The thing is I have uploaded and moved the file to my required location, no `.htaccess` rewrite rules have been applied and it's just a 226 kb pic that I want to upload and see.

Comment: Is the upload directory outside of the document root? How are you trying to call the picture?

Comment: It's not outside the document root and I am simply trying to view it with one of those photo viewer apps.

Comment: So are you viewing the Linux file system from a Windows box by accessing a shared folder or NFS mount or something of the like? Have you tried viewing the picture by ftp? I.e. [ftp://www.myexample.com/uploads/mypic.jpg](ftp://www.myexample.com/uploads/mypic.jpg)